# Meaning of "The air is thin up here"

Tags: meaning, expressions, idioms

What does "The air is thin up here" mean?

Does it have a positive connotation? E.g. when you are wearing heels in order to look taller.

Comment: Literally, it refers to the fact that the atmosphere is less dense the further you get from sea level (by climbing a mountain, being in a hot-air balloon ...) Figuratively, it may be used as in this example from the internet; 'The Air Is Thin Up Here. This new heightened sense of self is making it hard to breathe.' The 'rarified air' metaphor.

Comment: I expect a positive meaning e.x. when you are wearing high heels in order to look taller.

Comment: While *rare* and *thin* are often thought to be positive traits, in this case they work against the hearty, robust life.

Comment: As an aside, there is no such thing as "e.x." You mean "e.g." (or perhaps "ex.", though you shouldn't be using that, either).

Answer (score 3):

It is a fact of physics that as you start leaving the earth's atmosphere the amount of oxygen molecules, AKA air, decreases.

Anything "up", whether it be your moving in a spaceship out of the earth's atmosphere or **your being in a special neighborhood or your belonging to a special club or a socio-economic level**, brings you to an area where **the "air" is rare and thin.**

Comment: Yes; your illustrations are good.

Comment: Back to the O.P.'s question, I don't think it's meant to be a compliment or an insult – it's just meant to be a little silly (for the reasons Josh mentions). It's pretty similar to when a shorter person asks a taller person, "What's the weather like up there?"